# CommandNotFoundException raised for scp.exe (OpenSSH) called by powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scp, openssh

my problem is, that a PowerShell script, triggered by a batch that's triggered from an Outlook rule throws this exception:

```
scp : Die Benennung "scp" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren
Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und
wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In C:\Skripte\PowerShell\***_Bestellung.ps1:46 Zeichen:9
+ $SCP1 = scp -r ***@***.de:$($DirSour1) $($DirDest)
+         ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When I run the PS scrip from VSCode or execute the batch there is no problem, everthing works as expected.

First I thought something was wrong with the path. But adding the absolute path didn't help.
I tried `$cmd="$((Get-Command "scp.exe").Path) -r"` to put it in
`Invoke-Expression "$($cmd) $($con):$($DirSour1) $($DirDest)`, which didn't not fix the issue.

```
Get-Command : Die Benennung "scp.exe" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines
ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern
enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In C:\Lokale_Skripte\***_Bestellung.ps1:45 Zeichen:10
+ $cmd="$((Get-Command "scp.exe").Path) -r"
```

I found some questions here, stating that the location of `OpenSSH` folder might cause problems, so I moved it to `C:\Program Files`, changed PATH and rebooted my pc. But now the script crashes before the exception is thrown. I already changed it back, but now I'm wondering what else might be a/the problem.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2673
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2673
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

OpenSSH is version 8.1.0.1 installed via "Optional features" on Windows 10.

You think it's a permissions issue? I already tried the scp command in powershell with "normal" and administrator prompt, without problems.
I hope this is enough information.

Any help and thoughts appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using Invoke-Command and make "-r" an argument : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: The fact that `Get-Command scp.exe` fails to locate the executable indeed indicates that the `...\OpenSSH\bin` folder containing it is not in the `PATH` env variable of the Outlook process (which PowerShell will inherit when launched by outlook). Have you tried adding the openssh bin folder to the system-wide PATH variable (rather than moving the installation folder around)?

Comment: @jdweng Haven't used it before and I don't really get what you mean. Something like
`$parameters = @{
    ScriptBlock  = {
        Param ($param1, $param2)
    }
    ArgumentList = 'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe', '-r'
}
Invoke-Command @parameters`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I mentioned that I changed PATH, which already was system wide not only for my user. Should have added that. I also changed it back after moving the installation folder.

Comment: See following example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.3#example-12-use-the-args-automatic-variable-in-a-script-block

Comment: After I had rewritten my script in python, which fixed the issue, someone I asked via GitHub answered that it might be related to Office 32-bit. It was'nt installed on my old PC but is on the new one (don't aks why). I didn't try it, but maybe it'll help someone later on. Thanks for your help @jdweng